# MySQL SELECT slow, but only 2 x 300K rows and indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, join, select

Have the MySQL SELECT query below that is awfully slow.

It takes ~1.0 seconds to execute despite having only 300K rows and indexes, so I would love to find a way to get it to execute faster since it's a query that needs to be run again and again.

The query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.image, c.name, s.name, MIN(p.saleprice)
FROM products p 
JOIN shops s ON p.shopid = s.id 
JOIN products_category pc ON p.id = pc.product_id 
JOIN categories c ON pc.category_id = c.id
WHERE p.brand_id > 0
AND pc.category_id = 46
AND pc.active = 1
AND p.price > 0
AND p.saleprice > 0
AND p.saleprice < p.price
AND (p.last_seen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
GROUP BY p.image
```

The query returns 960 rows.

The table **products** has 300.000 rows and these columns + one index:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shopid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saleprice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_seen` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `brand_id etc` (`brand_id`,`shopid`,`last_seen`,`price`,`saleprice`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=391671 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The table **products_categories** also has 300.000 rows and these columns + two indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category_id etc` (`category_id`,`active`),
  KEY `product_id etc` (`product_id`,`active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=373364 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The ***shops*** table. It has 15 rows and these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `shops` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Based on similar questions here, I have tried nesting things with an inner select:

```
SELECT p.id, p.image, c.name, s.name, MIN(p.saleprice)
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE p.brand_id > 0 AND price > 0 AND saleprice > 0 AND saleprice < price AND (p.last_seen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))) p 
JOIN shops s ON p.shopid = s.id 
JOIN products_category pc ON p.id = pc.product_id 
JOIN categories c ON pc.category_id = c.id 
WHERE pc.category_id = 46
AND pc.active = 1
GROUP BY p.image
```

It didn't help. The version with the inner select takes ~1,3 seconds to execute.

The problem seems to be the join between products and products_category, i.e. the two big tables with 300K rows each.

The **GROUP BY p.image** is necessary (some products are just different sizes, so we use p.image to filter these out).

Maybe there's a trick I can do with my indexes? Or can any of you spot something else I should optimize?

EXPLAIN of the query:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys                   key             key_len ref             rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      c       \N          const   PRIMARY                         PRIMARY         4       const           1       100.00      Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      pc      \N          ref     category_id etc,product_id etc  category_id etc 10      const,const     43104   100.00      Using where
1   SIMPLE      p       \N          eq_ref  PRIMARY,brand_id etc            PRIMARY         4       pc.product_id   1       5.00        Using where
1   SIMPLE      s       \N          eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY         4       p.shopid        1       100.00      \N
```

Comment: please add full table definitions and output of explain for the query

Comment: 1) Add DDL for all tables. 2) Add EXPLAIN. 3) Add tablename aliases to ALL columns names used in the query.

Comment: Good points. I have updated my question with table columns + explain. Aliases should be in the query.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! If you want to be sure that someone sees your message, put @ + their_name in it (no spaces).For me, it would be @Vérace for example , but you can only notify one person per comment.

Comment: as we said we need to see CREATE TABLE, not just the list of columns with data types

Comment: did you try to add index on products(last_seen)? why do you need to use GROUP BY on image column?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; _and_ tag each column with the table it is in.  `last_seen` and `brand_id` are too ambiguous.  Also see this for improving the many:many mapping table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: CREATE TABLEs added. The group by is necessary (explanation added), but adding an index on p.image alone helped a bit. The query then takes 0.7 seconds to run.

Comment: @Mads Are you happy with current performance and we can go on to other Questions?  Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @WilsonHauck ~0.7 seconds is surely an improvement, but I wish it could be faster than that. It's a query that is used thousands of times every day, so every 0.1 second improvement counts! Any ideas for improving the query further is therefore super welcome and very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Mads Additional info request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, but I already got a great answer below. Query speed is now ~0.3 seconds which is a great improvement. So I would say I'm happy with the new performance.

Comment: To be elated, let us complete a server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> KEY `brand_id etc` (`brand_id`,`shopid`,`last_seen`,`price`,`saleprice`)

This index does not support this query well.

The first field in the index is brand_id, but you are only filtering by "> 0".
Since I doubt you have many brands with *negative* id's, this probably isn't going to help very much.

The next field in the index is shopid, which doesn't appear in your where clause at all.

Based on this cursory analysis (and MySQL will do a *lot* more than that), this index will probably be discounted and the table scanned serially instead.

A better discriminator for choosing the rows you want returned would be **last_seen**.  Consider adding an index on that (or with that as its first field) and you should see some improvement.

Comment: Great points. Thanks a lot. Best performance so far is a new index on image, last_seen => the query now takes ~0.3 seconds which is a big improvement to the original ~1.0 seconds.